# Is there a way to print the output of the Visual Studio "compare with unmodified" diff tool?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm rearranging a lot of code and it would be nice to print the output of the "Compare with Unmodified" window.

There doesn't appear to be a way, but perhaps there is some plug-in or some clever trick.  Can the VS diff command output a text diff similar to the Unix diff?

Comment: Why are you trying to print the output? If you commit the changes, that diff can be viewed at any time when inspecting your GIT history.

Comment: @TeaBaerd, I'm starting off a major refactorization, starting with the DB first.  There's going to be a lot of broken pieces lying around for a bit as I move things around.  After starting, it occurred to me that a diff on the SQL would be a helpful checklist.

Comment: This sounds like you need a Kanban/Scrum board where you can break out all the tasks you need to complete your refactor. From there each piece of refactor should be implemented atomically(at the smallest logical level) move a field from one object to another and migrate the data from old to new location and drop old column. Each of these pieces should be a migration within your schema control system. I'd recommend an ORM like EF to perform the migrations as it does a nice job organizing them by time. When you have enough logical pieces of the refactor done you can upgrade a db.

Comment: Thanks, @TeaBaerd.  That sounds very interesting. I've been learning about EF migrations, so I'm switching to EF code first to take advantage of that.  Do you have any recommended resources for learning about Kanban/Scrum boards?

Comment: I'd talk with an Atlassian salesperson. I've used Jira(atlassian's project management tool) and loved it. 
Talking to an Azure salesperson would also work. I'm working with Azure Devops(Microsoft's project management tool) and find it similarly effective. 
These people will try and sell you their version of the product but they also are packed with useful knowledge on how to migrate your existing processes to their specific solution. If you take them with a grain of salt, their suggestions for how to migrate to Kanban or any agile management process will be invaluable.